# How can I get rid of springtails?

Tags: pest-control

I don't exactly know how or why, but seems my house is starting to get more of these things - [springtails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springtail).

I've checked all over the internet, and it says there is too much moisture, however, they are living in areas between the concrete outside and the bricks. Is there a chemical I can pour/ or something I can use so this little critters will stop bugging me!!

Comment: Can you post a photo that shows an example of where they are living, getting into your home?

Answer (score 1):

They're normal in gardens, but it's understandable that you'd want to be rid of them.  Here are some [chemical solutions](http://www.domyownpestcontrol.com/springtails-c-160.html), and [other ways to control them](http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn74136.html).

Answer (score 0):

They will be killed with a solution called Sevin
They love moist conditions,,,, so if you have mulch or compost, just water the plants only. Pull the mulch away from your house and windows. They can and will invade your home, especially if you have pets!